# Electron-log with file transport is forcing app reload

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am using the electron-todo template and trying to create a log file that recovers the data in the event of a crash. The app reloads every time the log file is updated. How would I prevent the app from reloading every time? I intended the logging to occur in the background while the app keeps running. In the renderer I have the following:

```
const path = require("path");
const log = require("electron-log");
log.transports.file.resolvePath = () => path.join("renderer", 'main.log');

document.getElementById('todoForm').addEventListener('submit', (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault()
  const input = evt.target[0]
  ipcRenderer.send('add-todo', input.value)
  .then(()=>{
    log.info('Log todo:', input.value) //this is causing app to reload
  })
  .catch((err)=>{
    alert('Cannot log todo')
  })
})
```

I cannot see any console error output upon app reload, but the log file does record as it should.

Comment: What is the event target? Are you sure its indexable?

Comment: Hi Phix, thank you for the comment. I am not sure its indexable, my js knowledge is quite limited. I am using this as my starting point and wanted to log the inputs on a txt file. https://github.com/CodeDraken/electron-todo/blob/master/renderer/add.js

Comment: In other words, what is the value of `evt.target`? Is it an array of elements?